Unable to connect to Azure Storage account using Powershell Connect-AzAccount command
I am new to Azure , My Vendor has some information in their Azure Storage Account , They have made to so , we cannot access this storage account via SAS Token and we can only access it via Private Endpoint set up in our own Azure RG
We have done the same , Now I'm trying to import the data into my local server , i have enabled my local server to be able to access the private end point i created
I am trying to accomplish this using PowerShell but I'm getting below error when connecting to Azure
Error :

ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details


AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided,Ensure secret being sent is the client secret value

I have confirmed that secret key is correct
Please find my method in PowerShell below :
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password123!" -AsPlainText -Force
$TenantId = 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyy'
$ApplicationId = 'zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzz'
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential



AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided. Ensure the secret being sent is the client secret value.

The above error occurs when you provide an invalid secret value in the authentication.
You can find the client secret from the Azure portal.
Portal -> Microsoft Identity -> App registration -> your app -> Certificates & secrets -> copy the value.
Portal:

Now, using the below sample script, I can authenticate with the storage account to list the blobs.
Script:
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "D408Q~7xxxxxxz.lp~aOKbc8w" -AsPlainText -Force
$TenantId = 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyy'
$ApplicationId = 'zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzz'
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential


$storageAccountName = "venkat456"
$storageAccountKey = "YourStorageAccountKey"
$containerName = "test"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containerName 

Output:
Account                              SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
-------                              ---------------- --------                             -----------
34xxxxd3                                               22xxxxx0283                         AzureCloud 

ICloudBlob                         : Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob
BlobType                           : BlockBlob
Length                             : 5055
IsDeleted                          : False
BlobClient                         : Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient
BlobBaseClient                     : Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient
BlobProperties                     : Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobProperties
RemainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete : 
ContentType                        : text/html
LastModified                       : 22-05-2024 06:29:34 +00:00
SnapshotTime                       : 
ContinuationToken                  : 
VersionId                          : 
IsLatestVersion                    : 
AccessTier                         : Hot
TagCount                           : 0
Tags                               : 
ListBlobProperties                 : Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem
Context                            : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
Name                               : 20-05-2024 .html


Reference:
Sign in to Azure PowerShell with a service principal | Microsoft Learn
